# animate scale : buttons one after another with delay of 1/2 second in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to scale with delay of 1/2 sec from one button to another.When I tried increasing

```
anim.setStartOffset(500);
                    anim.setDuration(1000);
```

then its freezing the screens for 5 iterations and displaying all at once .Basically I cannot see transition in scaling.How can I see the transition?

```
            for (int i = 7; i > 2; i--) {
Animation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 0.5f, 1f, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                    anim.setFillAfter(true); 
                    anim.setStartOffset(10);
                    anim.setDuration(100);
                    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

                    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("button"+i, "id", getPackageName());
                    currcell = (Button) findViewById(id);
                    currcell.startAnimation(anim);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be is for that:
anim.setStartOffset(10);
10 ms is so fast